# MariaDB corrupted after attempting full backup with mariabackup

Tags: mariadb, corruption

I have Mariadb installed on a Raspberry Pi with a simple star schema for logging data that comes in on a Modbus server.  Everything was running fine for about a month and a half until one day I was met with errors about a corrupt database page.  This was the first time it happened.  Luckily I had a backup SD that I was able to recover the system from.

Today it happened again when I was trying to figure out another error that was occurring when trying to perform a full backup.
`sudo mariabackup --backup --target-dir "${full_path}"/base --user=root`
within my own script: "full_backup.sh".  The script has been working perfectly up until recently when I noticed the error.
[image]

I wasn't sure if I ran `sudo mysql_secure_installation` when I reinstalled mariadb after the first recovery, so I ran it and answered 'Y' to everything as usual.

Then, when I restarted mariadb `sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service` I was met with the same error I had the first time.
[image]

And when I looked in /var/log/mysql/error.log I saw the same error as last time there as well.
[image]

The first time I ran into this problem I spent hours researching what might be causing it to no avail.  I would greatly appreciate anyone out there who can help resolve this.  Thank you.

Update 1:  Tried following instructions here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/ under the "Table Corruption" section.  Clicked link to "InnoDB recovery mode" followed that rabbit hole and tried setting the variable to 1 like this: `mysqld_safe --innodb-force-recovery=1`  Checked the variable with: `mysqld --verbose --help | grep recovery` and the variable is not changing to 1.  It stays set to 0.

Update 2: Out of desparation I tried uninstalling and reinstalling mariadb.  `sudo apt purge mariadb-server` then `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/` then `sudo apt install mariadb-server`  Still getting the same error as before when I check `sudo systemctl status mariadb`  I'm running out of ideas.

Update 3: Just did `sudo apt purge mariadb*` then `sudo reboot`.  Now I can't SSH in.  The Pi is at a remote location.  What an absolute nightmare.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your question is. How the file got corrupted? How to restore it? Something else?

Comment: Why am I getting these errors?  How can I recover the database to a working state?